# reconstructing an object in C++ and assigning it to the same type

Tags: c++11

I have the following piece of code that I have a question about.

```
V v(10,0);//first argument is size and the second is init val for each element
...
v = V(5,0);
```

Does the previously allocated v get destroyed automatically when I call V(5,0) and assign it to v in the second line ? Is a new object of type V being created and assigned to v ? I don't fully understand what is happening behind the scene.

Comment: Sounds like it's time to read up on [assignment operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
V v(10,0);
```

The compiler will allocate some space on the callstack (not the heap), and then call the `V(int,int)` constructor on that place in memory, to construct the object.

```
v = V(5,0);
```

This is actually several parts, which I'll separate:

```
....V(5,0).
```

Again: The compiler will allocate some space on the callstack (not the heap), and then call the `V(int,int)` constructor on that place in memory, to construct the temporary unnamed object.

```
v = .......
```

The compiler calls the `v.operator=(const V&)` member, which presumably copies the contents from the parameter (the unnamed `V` temporary) to the named `v` object.

```
..........;
```

The expression is ended, so the compiler calls the `~V` destructor to destroy the temporary object, and then (probably) deallocates the space on the callstack for reuse later.

When the scope ends (usually: when the function ends), the compiler will automatically call  the `~V` destructor to destroy the named `v` object, and then deallocates the space on the callstack.

Comment: `operator=(const V&)` is the code for this operator generated by the compiler ?

Comment: what happens to the memory space that was allocated to `V(10,0)` ? Does that original object get destroyed or do I need to destroy that as well ?

Comment: When the function ends. Added to the answer.

Comment: @marc in C++ local variables have automatic storage duration. That is you don't have to manually destroy them.